# RowsAffected con OpenOrExecute Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, oracle-12c

Me encuentro trabajando con Delphi XE7 con conexión a SQL Server y Oracle, al realizar una consulta con un TFDQuery, posteriormente aplicar un OpenOrExecute y finalmente utilizando la propiedad RowsAffected obtengo el número de filas devueltas, pero al realizar estos mismos pasos con un INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE solo me devuelve un -1, utilizo OpenOrExecute debido a que se trata de consultas AdHoc ¿Sabrán que es lo que se debe de modificar para que si se obtenga el número de filas afectadas con INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE al utilizar OpenOrExecute?

Ejemplo:

--Esto si me devuelve la cantidad de filas

```
TFDQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM PERSONAS');
TFDQuery.OpenOrExecute;
TFDQuery.RowsAffected;
```

--Esto solo devuelve -1

```
TFDQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO PERSONAS VALUES (1,''MARIA'',''PEREZ'')');
TFDQuery.OpenOrExecute;
TFDQuery.RowsAffected;

TFDQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE PERSONAS SET NOMBRE=''ALEJANDRA'' WHERE ID=1');
TFDQuery.OpenOrExecute;
TFDQuery.RowsAffected;

TFDQuery.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM PERSONAS');
TFDQuery.OpenOrExecute;
TFDQuery.RowsAffected;
```

Comment: ¿Utilizas TQuery de; BDE? ¿Por qué no utilizas `Open` cuando es una sentencia `select` y `Execute`/`ExecSQL` cuando es `insert`/`update`/`delete`?

Comment: Si es TFDQuery, y utilizo OpenOrExecute porque son consultas AdHoc

Comment: `TFDQuery` no es `TQuery`. El primero pertenece a FireDAC y el segundo a BDE.

Comment: Disculpa ya corregí la pregunta, si utilizo FireDAC, por lo tanto un TFDQUERY

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el código de la implementación actual de TFDQuery, veo claramente que al utilizar el método `OpenOrExecute` no hay forma de recoger el valor de las filas afectadas. El método
simplemente intenta *abrir* el resultado del comando, como si se tratase de una sentencia `select` e ignora la excepción que ocurre si la sentencia no produce al menos un conjunto de datos como resultado.

La forma subyacente para obtener el número de filas afectadas por una sentencia `insert`/`update`/`delete` es distinta.

Una forma en la que podrías trabajar al-rededor de esta limitación es preparar el comando y, dependiendo del tipo de sentencia que el propio driver de FireDAC determina que se trata abrirlo o ejecutarlo, en cuyo caso la propiedad `RowsAffected` se actualiza correctamente.

La idea básica es:

- Asigna el SQL
- Prepara la sentencia
- Dale una mirada al valor de la propiedad `CommandKind` de la propiedad `Command` del `TFDQuery`, que va a tener uno de los valores `skSelect`, `skInsert`, `skUpdate`, entre otros.
- Dependiendo de ese valor, decides qué método ejecutar (`Open`, `ExecSQL`, `OpenOrExecute`)
- Si se ha ejecutado `Open` o `ExecSQL`, la propiedad `RowsAffected` te mostrará correctamente le número de filas afectadas.

El código que he probado es:

```delphi
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'tu sentencia aquí';
  FDQuery1.Prepare;

  if Assigned(FDQuery1.Command) then
    case FDQuery1.Command.CommandKind of
      skNotResolved,
      skUnknown: FDQuery1.OpenOrExecute;
      skSelect,
      skSelectForLock,
      skSelectForUnLock: FDQuery1.Open;
      skDelete,
      skInsert,
      skMerge,
      skUpdate,
      skCreate,
      skAlter,
      skDrop,
      skStoredProc,
      skStoredProcWithCrs,
      skStoredProcNoCrs,
      skExecute,
      skStartTransaction,
      skCommit,
      skRollback,
      skSet,
      skSetSchema,
      skOther: FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
    end
  else
    FDQuery1.OpenOrExecute;

  Label2.Caption := IntToStr(FDQuery1.RowsAffected);
end;
```

He hecho una prueba contra SQL Server y esto me ha funcionado razonablemente bien. Sugiero que antes de implementarlo lo pruebes también con Oracle (ya que depende del driver específico de la base de datos), y también que te asegures de realizar la operación correcta para cada tipo de sentencia (yo he hecho una prueba rápida, pero no puedo garantizar el resultado en casos como `skSelectForLock` o valores igualmente exóticos.

Answer (score 0):

He continuado investigando y parece ser que el metodo OpenOrExecute para los comandos Insert, Update y Delete no devuelve un conjunto de datos por tanto no se pueden contar las filas afectadas. El comando Select si devuelve un conjunto de datos por lo que se pueden contar las filas afectadas, por tanto te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
procedure MyOpenOrExecute(query: TFDQuery);
var
   txtConsulta: string;
   comando: string;
begin
   txtConsulta:=LowerCase(query.SQL.Text);  
   comando:= copy(txtConsulta,1,1);

   if(comando = "s")then
      query.Open
   else
      query.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Creas tu propio procedimiento MyOpenOrExecute para que puedas reutilizarlo las veces que desees, este procedimiento recibira como parametro tu componente TFDQuery. Lo que hara este procedimiento es copiar en la variable comando el primer caracter de la consulta que ya previamente habias armado.

Select => S

Insert => I

Update => U

Delete => D

Si el primer caracter es "s" entonces se llama a Open de no ser una "s" entonces se llama a ExecSQL

Comment: Esto fallaría con muchos comandos, para comenzar con lo más simple: `whth x as (select * from MiTabla) select campo from x`.

Comment: @jachguate, hasta ahora ella solo se ha referido a los 4 comandos básicos de manipulación de datos